# Is it correct to say "I prefer to get refunded on my original account"?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say "I prefer to ***get refunded*** on my original account" while a store asks me what refund option I would choose?

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but it's interesting you would be given the choice. In the UK any refund is to the method/card/account used to pay initially, & *nowhere* else. It prevents fraud & money laundering.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. many UK sellers will prefer to credit store account rather than incur fees repaying to card; almost every refund I've had from Amazon.co.uk worked like that.

Comment: My experience with Amazon UK is that I get the choice (gift card or original payment method) as in OP. Indeed I used Amazon as an example in my answer because it's so familiar.

Comment: @PeteKirkham - I've never had anyone, including Amazon, ask me to make a choice. Of course, the last thing you ever want is 'store credit' - it means they've still got your money & there's nothing more you can do about it. I would never accept that even back in the days we wrote cheques for things ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your actual question, prefer 'to *be* refunded' rather than 'get refunded'.

The result will be that you 'got a refund', but 'get' with the verb 'refunded' sounds odd to me.

Some other points:

1. 'I *would* prefer' - if you just say 'I prefer' it sounds habitual, a general preference for all refunds in your life;
2. '*to the* original account' is better than 'on my' I think, but then you need to say something like 'I would prefer the refund be to...' too;
3. '*when* a store', not 'while', as DS said;
4. 'a store' doesn't really 'ask' you anything, the employee does, but it's OK colloquially I suppose, particularly assuming in your real sentence it would be a specific company name ('Amazon asked me ...' sounds much more natural than 'a store asked me' to me, not that it's actually any more correct);
5. '*which* refund option' - that's routinely messed up by some native speakers, so don't worry much, but in general think 'which from a list' & 'what free-form text';
6. 'I would *like*', or 'asks me *to choose a refund option*' - 'which I would choose' as you wrote sounds like it was a hypothetical: 'if we were to refund you which would you want'.

Comment: I do not think "'I would prefer to be refunded" is natural or indeed correct. A person is not refunded, money is refunded. A person gets or receives a refund.

Comment: @DavidSiegel A person absolutely is refunded. The money is the refund (noun). ("Don't argue with the customer, just refund them.", "I only received half, please refund me the difference.", etc.)

Comment: @OJFord Your second example is not good here, since it has "(the) difference" as the direct object.

Answer (score 4):

That would not be a usual way of expressing that idea, and might confuse a fluent speaker, it would surely sound odd to many native speakers.

We do not usually speak of a person "getting refunded" but rather of a person "**getting a refund**".

We do not usually say "on my account" to indicate where a refund will go, but rather "into my account", or often there is an indication of which of several possible accounts will be credited.

Thus instead of:

> I prefer to get refunded on my original account [image: Red X, indicting incorrect or disfavored form]

one might say

> - I prefer to have the refund go to the account I used to make the purchase. [image: Green check mark, indicting an acceptable form]
> - Please send the refund to the account I used to make the purchase. [image: Green check mark, indicting an acceptable form]
> - I would like the refund put on to my Visa card ending in 1827 [image: Green check mark, indicting an acceptable form]
> - Please credit this card [showing the other person the card]  with the refund [image: Green check mark, indicting an acceptable form]
> - Please credit my account with the store. [image: Green check mark, indicting an acceptable form]
> - I want you to apply the refund to the same account I used to buy it. [image: Green check mark, indicting an acceptable form]
> - I want to get the refund in cash.[image: Green check mark, indicting an acceptable form]

Another answer suggest (indirectly):

> I would prefer to be refunded in X way. [image: Red X, indicting incorrect or disfavored form]

I do not think this is natural or indeed correct. A person is not refunded, money is refunded. A person gets or receives a refund.

---

By the way,  the form

> **while** a store asks me what refund option I would choose? [image: Red X, indicting incorrect or disfavored form]

is incorrect. You very likely  mean "when a store..." as "while" would suggest that you talked over the clerk's question.

Comment: I disagree that "getting refunded" is incorrect or even unnatural.  See these example sentences- From Cambridge dictionary: "The customer will be refunded in full up to $50,000."  From Google card (retrieved from Oxford Languages): "I'll refund you for the apples and any other damage"

Comment: You are wrong to say that I am wrong in your edit, I'm afraid. All your suggestions use 'refund' as a noun - this is fine - where it refers to the money. When used as a (transitive) verb it is the person (the one owed the money) that you 'refund', not the money.

Comment: @OJFord Yes, one can use "refund" as a verb, as in "I refunded the money to him." or "I will see that the money is refunded" or "We will refund the money to the customer."

Comment: @DavidSiegel If you find you can buy a reputable dictionary that says I'm wrong, I'll gladly refund you. ;)

Comment: "A person gets or receives a refund." - indeed, that is the process of *being refunded*.